# How to run ios application in background on device restart?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, background

I am working on Location Tracking Application. This application continuously send location even in background. I am using SLC property.

I am also using silent push trick for location tracking. Logic of Silent push:
Check AppIconbadge number and perform the action according to AppIconbadge number. I have a timer which check AppIconbadge at every 10 seconds.

Now this is the case:
Device is on SLC and put the app in background and turn off the device. While you switch back to On this device it is still reporting on SLC while Ping (Silent Push) is not working.

I have started the timer when app get SLC trigger. But its not working.

Can you help?

Comment: According to Apple documentation you application will fall in the track location background mode. Which will not allow you to be started when the device is restarted.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it.

The way iOS achieves great battery life and reduces RAM usage makes this kind of thing impossible.

Your only real possibility is to have your server send occasional push notifications to the device, and have your app on the device respond with its location. This is how Find My Phone and Find My Friends both work. The idea is to improve battery life by doing as much as possible on a server, which has mains power and virtually unlimited RAM, instead of on the phone which only has a battery and might need all it's RAM to play a 3D game

Basically the CPU is not running at all most of the time, so it can't schedule stuff to run periodically, and you can't rely on there being enough RAM available to run your app so it also can't be running all the time even if the CPU is powered on.

According to the WWDC 2013 keynote, push notifications are much more powerful on iOS 7, so you should look that up (I haven't looked into it myself, just saw the keynote.

Comment: Thank you, but you did not mention that why cant we that?

Comment: @user1829463 We can't do it because the hardware is designed in a way that makes it impossible. That's why an iPad lasts one week on a small cheap battery and a macbook lasts one day on a big expensive battery.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert I like your comparison between iPad and macbook.